# Querying device's telemetry/status/event from Azure IoT Central

Tags: azure-iot-sdk, azure-iot-central

I've created an Azure IoT Central solution, where I successfully registered an IoT device. I'm able to save telemetry/status/event data for the device, however I could not find an option to query the existing data using .NET code. For example I would like to query the telemetry data for the last month using C#.

Is it not supported by the SDK?

Answer (score 0):

In order to query the telemetry data for the last month you will need to export that to a Blob Storage or routing it to another DB (like Cosmos DB). The supported way to export your data in Azure IoT Central is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/howto-export-data).

You can then leverage REST API on your c# code to extract the data from your devices.

- [Read Avro files by using C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/howto-export-data-blob-storage#read-avro-files-by-using-c)
- [Azure Storage samples using .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-samples-dotnet?toc=%2fazure%2fstorage%2fblobs%2ftoc.json)
- [Azure Cosmos DB: .NET examples for the SQL API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-dotnet-samples)